# Angular ng-repeat and array filtering

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-filter

So I have the following array being repeated to list:

```
 <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom: currentPage*pageSize | limitTo: pageSize | filter: filterAll as filtered" ng-model="item.selected" ng-show="items.length" item="item" ng-class-even="&#039fade even&#039" ng-class-odd="&#039fade odd&#039">
```

Filtered with:

```
listModule.filter('startFrom', function () {
return function (input, start) {
    if (input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
 }
});

 $scope.filters = {
    RowNr: "",
    LocationNr: "",
    ItemType: "",
    ItemOwner: ""
};

 $scope.filterAll = function () {
    var result = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.filterFn);
    console.log(result.length);
    return result;
}

 $scope.filterFn = function (item) {
    var result = true;
    for (var filter in $scope.filters) {
        var obj = $scope.filters[filter];
        if (result) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(obj) || obj == null || obj == "" || filter == "ItemType" || filter == "ItemOwner") {
                result = true;
            }
            else if (filter == "LocationNr" || filter == "RowNr") {
                result = item[filter] === parseInt(obj);
            } else {
                result = item[filter] == obj;
            };
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

I can see the right result length being logged inside $scope.filterAll when I type in stuff in the filter inputs but the array displayed to the user wont update with filtered content?